# How to display a dictionary of items in a Listbox on Windows Phone, using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary

In here I opened a word/definition text file. And I trimmed it putting the word into `newword` and definition into `newdefn`. I placed it in a dictionary, created as follows:

`Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

which I declared as global. Since it is inside the `while(!endofstream)` loop, all the words and definitions are stored there.

My problem is how to put the values in my dictionary into a `listbox`.  My code:

```
    public search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                                
        Stream txtStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new
            Uri("/PanoramaApp1;component/word.txt", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtStream))
        {
            string jon;

            //definition.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();


            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                jon = sr.ReadLine();



                newword = (word.Trim(new Char[] { '-',' ' }));
                newdefn = (defn.Trim(new Char[] { '-',' ' }));                 

                d.Add(newword, newdefn);                                  
            }
        }                     
    }
```

I want now to do a search in a textbox and the results to be displayed in a listbox. But I have a problem with the part in the "textbox selection changed". I'm getting an error in the `listbox.Items.Add(str);`

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>(d.Keys);

 foreach (string str in list)
 {
     if (str.StartsWith(searchbox.Text, 
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
         listbox.Items.Add(str);
     }
 }
```

Comment: set the ItemsSource property of the ListBox to the dictionary: `yourListBox.ItemsSource = d;`

Comment: oh worked. and it is printed like [word, defintion] format. can i ask a next question? how do i print only the word only. and if i click it, its pair will show in a messagebox/textblock
thank you bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `Dictionary` as the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListBox`:

```
yourListBox.ItemsSource = d;
```

You can customize how you want to show the items using a `DataTemplate` for the Items. For example to only show the word:

```xaml
<ListBox  Name="yourListBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Tap="Item_Tap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And to show the definition in a MessageBox when an item is tapped, you can do the following in the event handler:

```
private void Item_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as TextBlock;
    MessageBox.Show(d[s.Text]);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, I mistakenly was showing the Value, when I should be showing the Key. `Text="{Binding Key}"`

Comment: another error that says Error 1 The attachable property 'ItemTemplate' was not found in type 'ListBox'. sorry im really new to C# T_T

Comment: The code from the answer works ok. Have you modified something in yours? Make sure that `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` element is inside a `<ListBox>` element.

Comment: sorry my bad, it works perfectly now bro. thumbs up to you. thank you

Comment: i guess you need to bind the textbox to thelist before displaying the results?